# How to float div in multiple columns? Without "left, center, right" div tag

Tags: css, css-float

There's the groups I need to list in multiple columns like this.

[image]

I tried but it seems not working with `float: left;`.

My result is this.

[image]

The problem is, I can't specify `div` like `left` or `right`, or `center`.

Because the group list is retrieved from DB. So the list size varies, and the column numbers too.

Here's my test source.

```
<style>
#box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 230px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.group span {
    font-weight: bold; 
}

.group {
    float: left;
    width: 65px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: green;
}
</style>

<div id="box">

    <div class="group">
        <span>group 1</span>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
    </div>

    <div class="group">
        <span>group 2</span>
        <li>item3</li>
    </div>

    <div class="group">
        <span>group 3</span>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
    </div>

    <div class="group">
        <span>group 4</span>
        <li>item10</li>
    </div>

    <div class="group">
        <span>group 5</span>
        <li>item30</li>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple column layout:

```
column-count:3;
```

However, only IE10 supports it alone. For Firefox and Chrome:

```
-moz-column-count:3;
-webkit-column-count:3;
```

Comment: No chance to IE7~9 and Safari?

Comment: Safari is Webkit, so that's fine. IE7-9 however are not and will display a single, wide column. Perhaps you can use `float:left` if the way you currently have it showing is acceptable enough for unsupporting browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may help you 
http://jsfiddle.net/qyQLu/

HTML code

```
<div id="box">
    <div class="newclass">
        <div class="group">
            <span>group 1</span>
            <li>item1</li>
            <li>item2</li>
            <li>item3</li>
        </div>

        <div class="group">
            <span>group 2</span>
            <li>item3</li>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class ="newclass">
        <div class="group">
            <span>group 3</span>
            <li>item1</li>
            <li>item2</li>
            <li>item3</li>
            <li>item2</li>
            <li>item3</li>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newclass">
        <div class="group">
            <span>group 4</span>
            <li>item10</li>
        </div>

        <div class="group">
            <span>group 5</span>
            <li>item30</li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS code

```
#box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 230px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.newclass
{
  width:65px;
  float:left;
  padding-left:5px;
}

.group span {
    font-weight: bold; 
}

.group {
    float: left;
    width: 65px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I can't decide when to create `.newclass`. Because the `.group` is retrieved from DB. And it displays with `loop` in programming language(mine is JSP).

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that comes in my mind is using a different class for all the blocks and play with `clear: both;`,if the position of the element is offset you need using a margin, or else you can give up the floating and using the position